# I create a new model in custom vision. How can I use this model in computer vision?

Tags: computer-vision, microsoft-custom-vision

As I said, I create a new mode by Custom Vision. Now, I want to analyze other image using this model. Is it possible? What endpoint should I use? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you used www.customvision.ai to create your "model".

Computer Vision and Custom Vision are 2 different products:

- Computer Vision API is the API with pre-trained, ready-to-use methods about vision (describe image, OCR, etc.)
- Custom Vision API is the customized "brother" of Computer Vision: here you create your own "models" (called "project").

The process for Custom Vision is the following:
after your project creation, you import images in it, tag those images (full image for classification, bounding boxes for object detection), then train it, and finally publish it.

Once published, your "model" is exposed by an endpoint provided by Microsoft. All the details are provided in the "Prediction URL" display:

[image: prediction url]

This item can be displayed once you have trained and published your iteration.

Comment: Hello Sir, I have some questions about the azure custom vision. What is the architecture used in custom object detection? Any documentation about the model? Also, what are the classes(objects) that the model was trained on? Can I add more classes( objects) with keeping the original objects?

Comment: Custom Vision has no "default" classes that are provided. You are training it with your own data, so you define your own classes and you will get only those classes in terms of results

Comment: I meant the pre-trained model that is provided on the site where you can upload an image and it detects objects. how many objects is it trained on and what are they? and can I add more classes to them. I read in the documentations that there thousands of classes. Is there more documentation about what the classes are?. Thanks for your reply

Comment: So you are talking about Computer Vision API, not Custom Vision. The exact list of classes is difficult to find, I can't get it in the documentation and it is evolving